# How to get elements by class and provide CSS effects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to get elements by class?

I was providing blink effect to a text in a div using an external JavaScript but now I want to provide this effect to multiple div tags.
So I need to give divs a `class = blink` instead of `id = blink`.
How do I do provide same effect to multiple divs with class = 'blink'?

My initial JavaScript for providing blink effect to single div was as follow.

```
function blinkFont() {
    document.getElementById("blink").style.color = "white"    
    setTimeout("setblinkFont()", 500)
}

function setblinkFont() {
    document.getElementById("blink").style.color = "black"    
    setTimeout("blinkFont()", 500)
}
```

I have tried this and its not working...

```
var blinks = document.getElementsByClassName('blink');
for (var i = 0; i < blinks.length; i++) {
    function blinkFont() {
        blinks[i].style.color = "white"
        setTimeout("setblinkFont()", 500)
    }
    function setblinkFont() {
        blinks[i].style.color = "black"
        setTimeout("blinkFont()", 500)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use native Javascript, `getElementsByClassName()` is the way to go. It should be noted, however that this returns a collection of elements, like an array. You can loop over this array and apply the style like so:

```
var blinks = document.getElementsByClassName('blink');
for(var i = 0; i < blinks.length; i++) {
    blinks[i].style.color = "white" // Or any other color you'd like.
}
```

More information on this function can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName).

Be aware though, that `getElementsByClassName()` is not supported by IE8 or lower. [Source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname). If you'd like to have this functionality in older browsers as well, I suggest you look into a framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/), which support CSS-like selectors that can be used to find the elements you're looking for.

Comment: Try the code in this JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Gv2u3/1/
You can obviously change the colour to whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using jQuery. For example you can implement some simple jQuery plugin like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.blink = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            delay: 500
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            var obj = $(this);
            setInterval(function() {
                if ($(obj).css("visibility") == "visible") {
                    $(obj).css('visibility', 'hidden');
                }
                else {
                    $(obj).css('visibility', 'visible');
                }
            }, options.delay);
        });
    }
}(jQuery))
```

and apply it to all elements marked with class 'blink':

```
$('.blink').blink();
```